# Headers in excel get replaced

Tags: vba, excel

I am pasting data from a record set in Excel. I have already named the first row as header, manually. Now I am pasting data starting from second row, but my headers get replaced by data in first row itself. Can anybody guess as what can be the problem?

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A2:DH" & lastrow).Cells.ClearContents
    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

**Edit:** The First and Second row are same. i.e Header is replaced by data which is supposed to be the first row of data and it is not the case from where the data is pulled. May be this provides some more info on what can be the problem.

Comment: Check which line is causing your problem by removing one of the 2 in the `With`

Comment: I have already labelled row 1. I want data to start from row 2, but data starts from 1 only and row 1 and row 2 are showing same data

Comment: Did you try setting the ActiveCell to "A2", and then copying the recordset? Like `ActiveCell = Range("A2")` before the `with` block, and `.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` inside the block?